# Extract value from an xmlstring in db2

Tags: db2

I have an XML string in a column called `RawData` from table `Inbound`. I have to read value `Success` from an element called `status`.

xmlstring:

```xml
<InboundMessage>
  <Transaction>
    <Status>Success</Status>
  </Transaction>
</InboundMessage>
```

Comment: This is my xml string : <InboundMessage><Transaction><Status>Success</Status></Transaction></InboundMessage>

Comment: And what is the query you tried and the problem you ran into?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT X.STATUS
FROM (VALUES XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT '
<InboundMessage>
  <Transaction>
    <Status>Success</Status>
  </Transaction>
</InboundMessage>
')) T (DOC)
, XMLTABLE
(
'$D/InboundMessage/Transaction/Status' PASSING T.DOC AS "D" COLUMNS
  STATUS VARCHAR(20) PATH '.'
) X;
```

Refer to the [XMLTABLE function overview](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.xml.doc/doc/c0023903.html) link for more details.